# How to customise Migrations History table after first migration was applied

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to relate Migrations History entries to version of software by which migration was performed. So far best place for that seems additional column in Migrations History table which can be filled with software version against each migration.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx) nicely describes how to make it, however it states:

> Before you start you need to know that you can customize the
> migrations history table only before you apply the first migration.

I don't believe this. Is there any way of achieving this? Maybe it is possible to change this table within another migration, however I am not sure about consequences, can anyone please advice on this matter?

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: @DavidG Not yet, I am not even sure if this is a best way of achieving this or maybe there is proved steps to make it. I have no doubts that I can add  a new column to the table, but main problem and reason for asking is that I am not sure how that might affect EF

Comment: Give it a try, here's an answer I wrote some time ago on how to add a column http://stackoverflow.com/a/24025775/1663001