# Why my app is searching for table that doesn't / shouldn't exist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, migration, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have created an MVC app in which I renamed a model class from "Diplomata" to "Diplomas" and now I can't make the migrations to create a table with name "Diplomas", because they still use the old name for some reason. (using .NET Framework 4.6 and EntityFramework 6.1.2)

things I have tried so far:

- dropping the db tables completely (from Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer and deleting the files manually)
- deleting the migration folder and re-enabling migrations
- deleting the model and re-creating it (after deleting migrations and dropping the tables completely)

After enabling migrations again and using command "add-migration Initial" I get a script that generates a table with name "dbo.Diplomata"

this is the model

```
namespace DDS.Data.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using DDS.Data.Common.Models;

    public class Diploma : BaseModel<int>
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is the ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    ...
    public IDbSet<Diploma> Diplomas { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and this is the part of the migration script that is automatically generated

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Diplomata",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Title = c.String(),
                Description = c.String(),
     ...
}
```

Also running a search in VS2015 for "Diplomata" in the entire solution doesn't find anything.

Adding a migration that is renaming the table makes the app crash after the update, because it is searching for a table with the old name. (Invalid object name 'dbo.Diplomata')

I have been debugging this all day with no result so any ideas or suggestions for where and what to look for are appreciated.

PS: This is my first question here so if I missed something or something is hard to understand please tell me, thank you

Comment: There is no fluent code (OnModelCreating) ? You could try changing your initializer to DropCreateDatabaseAlways and see if that creates the correct tables. Everything else looks correct.

Comment: DropCreateDatabaseAlways didn't help. I noticed that when i try to rename the table with a migration in the package manager console after executing Update-Database i get this warning: _Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures._ Witch tells me that there may be some scripts that I need to get rid off @SteveGreene

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cleaning the migrations table? When migrations are enabled, a system table called "__MigrationHistory" is generated. You can locate such table from within SQL Server Management Studio. Go to YourDatabase->Tables->System Tables and it's going to be there.

The way migrations work is as follows:

1. An initial migration is generated with a specified name.
2. The initial migration is executed.
3. When the initial migration and subsequent migrations are run, the changes are applied to the database and a snapshot of the structure of the database it's saved in the __MigrationHIstory table as a new row.
4. When the application initializaes, EF will compare the latest record in the migrations table and compare that snapshot with the latest migration available, if they don't match, an exception will be thrown. This is how EF determines whether or not the Database changed.

When you are making changes to the original model, you are supposed to create subsequent migration files so you can revert or apply database changes. If you already deleted the initial migration file, probably your best option will be to clean the __MigrationHistory table. EF generates unique entries in the table (I believe that the default behavior is the name of the migration file + a timestamp when the migration was generated). You can always rename the initial migration file to match with the name in the __MigrationHistory table and create a new migration to apply the rename of the table in question. This will only work if the name of the files and model match the snapshots in the DB, otherwise an exception will be thrown

Take a look to this article for more information about migrations:
http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/03/inside_of_ef_migrations/

As a side note, you can also modify the default behavior oh how the migration history table is generated. This may be helpful in the event you need to support specific needs, such as renaming it, not generate it as a system table, add additional columns, etc. This will be helpful in certain scenarios. Check the following link (Particularly useful for cloud-based databases):
[How do I add an additional column to the __MigrationHistory table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025075/how-do-i-add-an-additional-column-to-the-migrationhistory-table)

NOTE: It is important to mention that tables that are not contained in the initial model or subsequent models will be excluded from the model validation. This is specially useful if you want to create tables that shouldn't be monitored by EF. I.E: The membership provider tables.

I hope this helps clarifying the problems you are having.

Comment: Thank you for your time :)
It's a small project and I don't need the data in the tables to be saved so I deleted all tables including the migration's one
The problem with renaming the table in a new migration is this: Invalid object name 'dbo.Diplomata'
It is trying to use the old name, which I find weird because it is not hard coded anywhere in the project

Answer (score 0):

After few more trials and errors I gave up on fixing the problem. Instead I forced the app to created the model in a table with the name I wanted by adding Table attribute on the model. So now the model looks like this:

```
[Table("Diplomas")]
public class Diploma : BaseModel<int>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```