# EF 6 - Adding Custom Fields/Data to the __MigrationHistory table

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Based on these two links

[Customizing the Migrations History Table (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841)

[Add an Additional Column to MigrationHistory table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025075/how-do-i-add-an-additional-column-to-the-migrationhistory-table)

I was able to customize my Entity Framework 6 __MigrationHistory table in SQL. I needed to add a new column called **SoftwareVersion**. I have **AutomaticMigrationsEnabled** and whenever an entity changes, a new migration is automatically generated. I then call the **Update** method on the **DbMigrator** class and the database gets updated and a new record is created in __MigrationHistory table. The **SoftwareVersion** column is there (and obviously null) as is a new column called **Discriminator** which has the value of "HistoryRow".

Now that I have successfully customized the __MigrationHistory table I am at a loss as to how to actually insert data into the **SoftwareVersion** field! I've tried using the **HistoryContext** to update the record like so:

```
using(TitanHistoryContext context = new TitanHistoryContext(dbConnection, defaultSchema))
{
  TitanHistoryRow historyRow = context.History.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MigrationId == "201607271705375_InitialCreate");
  history.SoftwareVersion = "ABC123";
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is **historyRow** is always null. I found out that the reason it is null is because the context is attempting to query the history table looking for the **Discriminator** field to be set to "TitanHistoryRow" when that field actually holds the value "HistoryRow". I'm guessing this is because the Automatic Migration is using the **HistoryContext** by default instead of my custom **TitanHistoryContext**? Please help :)

```
{SELECT 
'0X0X' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
[Extent1].[ContextKey] AS [ContextKey], 
[Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], 
[Extent1].[EntityFrameworkVersion] AS [EntityFrameworkVersion], 
[Extent1].[ManifestVersion] AS [ManifestVersion]
FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'TitanHistoryRow'}
```

The record in the database looks like this:

```
 MigrationId                    ContextKey                                  Model            EntityFrameworkVersion  ManifestVersion      Discriminator
201607271705375_InitialCreate   Atl.Titan.Services.DataModel.TitanContext   0x1F8B08000000..  6.1.3-40302             NULL                HistoryRow
```

===========================================================================
Here is the code I am using to customize the __MigrationHistory table:

Custom HistoryRow class

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History;

namespace Atl.Titan.Services.DataAccess.Migrations
{
 public class TitanHistoryRow : HistoryRow
 {
    public string SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
 }
}
```

HistoryContext

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History;

namespace Atl.Titan.Services.DataAccess.Migrations
{
 public class TitanHistoryContext : HistoryContext
 {
    public TitanHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
        : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Configure table/column names and other properties here if needed
         modelBuilder.Entity<TitanHistoryRow>().Property(p => p.ProductVersion).HasColumnName("EntityFrameworkVersion");
    }

    public new DbSet<TitanHistoryRow> History { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Configuration

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Atl.Titan.Services.DataAccess.Migrations
{
 public class TitanHistoryConfiguration : DbConfiguration
 {
    public TitanHistoryConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetHistoryContext("System.Data.SqlClient",(connection, defaultSchema) => new TitanHistoryContext(connection, defaultSchema));
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to have two classes using the same DB table (AKA Table per Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance), Entity Framework will add a `Discriminator` column, and since EF's DB migration code explicitly uses a `DbSet<HistoryRow>` and your code would use a `DbSet<TitanHistoryRow>`, that means you cannot add anything to the same row that contains migration history data. What I did was to instead use Table per Type (TPT) inheritance by using a `[Table(MigrationHistory)]` attribute on the `TitanHistoryRow` class, so it would have a separate table, and I could add values to it that have foreign key values matching the `MigrationId` and `ContextKey` values from the `__MigrationHistory` table, so `DbSet<TitanHistoryRow>` queries would have useful data instead of completely separate data. (see also this other person's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025775/2016290)